# How to deploy a batch class through change sets without a test coverage for that class?

Tags: apex, unit-test, batch, deployment, change-set

I want to deploy only one class (batch) from sandbox to production and that class have only 10% test coverage but overall code has 80% test coverage.
Would it be possible to deploy that class by selecting "run all tests" during deployment?

Should I also take some other conditions into consideration?

Answer (score 4):

To answer you question yes you would be able to deploy the batch class if the overall coverage is more than 75% including this batch class as well and running all tests. But it is recommended  and best practice  to write the test class for each class and covers an average of 75% at-least. Please find the below article for best [practices](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000328615&type=1) while working with test classes.